# Decoding bitmaps from assets and adding to listview lag in Android

Tags: image, bitmap, adapter, loading

I am trying to make list view with Bitmap images from assets folder. Everything looks fine, but I get a big lag while loading listview or srolling it, what  I did wrong? Can I speed up loading?
This is how I get image from assets and decode it:

```
    private Bitmap imageFromAssets(int id, int type){
        String path ="/";

        if(type == 0)
            path = "weeds/"+id;
        else if(type == 1)
            path = "diseases/"+id;
        else if(type == 2)
            path = "insects/"+id;


        Resources res = getResources(); 
        AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
        String fileList[] = null;
        try {
            fileList = am.list(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream istr = null;
        if(fileList.length > 0)
            try {
                istr = am.open(path+"/"+fileList[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null ,options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 80, 80);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null, options);
    }



 public int calculateInSampleSize(  
         BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
         // Raw height and width of image
         final int height = options.outHeight;
         final int width = options.outWidth;
         int inSampleSize = 1;

         if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
          if (width > height) {
           inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);   
          } else {
           inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);   
          }   
         }

         return inSampleSize;   
   }
```

And adapter:

```
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listMap, R.layout.list_item_1_line_image, new String[] { "name", "id", "type"}, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.hidden_id, R.id.hidden_type}){ 
            @Override
                  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                      View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                      ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                      TextView id_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id);
                      TextView type_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hidden_type);
                      int id = Integer.parseInt(id_txt.getText().toString());
                      int type = Integer.parseInt(type_txt.getText().toString());
                      Bitmap bitmap = imageFromAssets(id, type);
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
                      image.setLayoutParams(lp);
                      image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                      image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                      return view;
                  };
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I solved my problem. I used ANdroid Universal Image Loader ([link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)) and removed `imageFromAssets` calling in `getView()`. Now everything works fast and smooth.